# how can we store a UIButton to an NSDictionary?

Tags: iphone, ios

I need to pass multiple arguments with `NSTimer` `userinfo` , I set the multiple argumets to an `NSDictionary` and passing the `NSDictionary`. My question is how can we store a `UIButton` object to an `NSDIctionary`?

Comment: Its pretty straightforward. Please try the thing yourself before posting the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSMutableDictionary * myDic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[myDic setObject:myButton forKey:@"button"];
```

Access it as following :

```
[myDic objectForKey:@"button"];
```

**hope this will help you.**

Comment: @Arunkumar : if this has helped you then I would appreciate if you accept the answer.